# wuauclt /resetauthorization /detectnow - not detecting updates when called remotely

Tags: powershell, windows-update

When I am trying to run wuauclt /resetauthorization /detectnow from a remote computer using the following line of code, the client is detecting 0 updates(writing an entry in log file).

```
$username = "uname"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "pass" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password
Invoke-command -Computer ComputerName -Credential $cred -Script {wuauclt /resetauthorization /detectnow}
```

But as soon as I run it manually on the same system it is detecting the updates.
What can cause this command to not detect updates when called remotely?

Comment: Did you check the content of %systemroot%\WindowsUpdate.log on the remote computer?

Comment: yes it also has 0 updates.